# New session when remoting Ubuntu 12.04 from mac

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop to remotely access to my desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 (with `xrdp` installed) from my MacBook Pro, using the same username as in the desktop. I can successfully log in Ubuntu 12.04. However, it gives me a new session with nothing opened on the screen (I do have something opened on my desktop, e.g. browser). May I know if there is any thing I can set to make Microsoft Remote Desktop share the same session&screen as shown on the desktop?

Thanks!